# Microsoft Cognitive API for Image Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, cortana

Do we have a Microsoft Cognitive API which is similar to google Image search, in which we upload a image and google will return search results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by specifiying `modulesRequested=SimilarImages`, like this:

```
curl "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?modulesRequested=SimilarImages" \
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $BING_API_KEY" \
-F "imgUrl=@cat.jpg"
```

The full spec for image search is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760791.aspx).